# What's the best way to find the minimum over all columns of strings in a tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

Suppose I have a tibble such as

```
t <- tibble(
  x = c("a", "b", "c"),
  y = c("d", "e", "f"),
  z = c("g", "h", "i")
)
```

and I would like to find the minimum value over all values in all columns. What's the best way to do this within the Tidyverse mindset?

If I try `min(t)`, I get the error

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
```

The only ways I've found to do this so far involve extracting out the individual vectors and finding the min over those. For example, `t_min <- min(c(t$x, t$y, t$z))` gives `"a"`. This works, but it doesn't extend well to many columns.

Note: assume that the "min" function gives the desired result when applied to the string data.

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`/`dplyr` you can

```
library(tidyverse)

t %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), min))

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  x     y     z    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     d     g
```

Minimum of the dataset

```
t %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), min)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(min = min(c_across(x:z)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the min value from each column (thanks [@benson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73168833/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-minimum-over-all-columns-of-strings-in-a-tibble/73168852#comment129224565_73168852) for the clean implementation):

```r
sapply(t, min)
#   x   y   z 
# "a" "d" "g"
```

And how to get the min value from an entire tibble (thanks to [@m--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73168833/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-minimum-over-all-columns-of-strings-in-a-tibble/73168852?noredirect=1#comment129224486_73168852) for pointing out that it's not necessary to `unname()` the vector before taking the `min()`):

```
min(unlist(t))
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: Maybe `sapply(t, min)` is cleaner

Comment: @benson23 updated and attributed

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `apply`:

```r
library(tibble)

apply(t, 2, min)

#>   x   y   z 
#> "a" "d" "g"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rlang::exec()` to splice your columns into a call to `c()`, and then call `min()` on the result:

```r
min(rlang::exec(c, !!!t))
#> [1] "a"
```

A similar approach in base R is to use `do.call()`:

```r
min(do.call(c, t))
#> [1] "a"
```